# TF400023 Error in TFS after cancel reconcilation

Tags: tfs, build, workspace

I ran a Build on my TFS...

I deleted a Folder in our Workspace and then checked this change in. 
The Build ran successfully and then the Reconcile Message Popped up and I accidently clicked "Cancel".

Now TFS cannot reconcile my workspace with the server.

I tried to reconcile with the latest Build by Builds -> Latest Build -> Reconcile with Workspace. It said that there were no pending changes to reconcile.

I even ran the studio as an Admin.

How can I fix this???

Answer (score 1):

The popped up "reconcile workspace" is part of [Build Notification application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181725(v=vs.120).aspx). Try to open the notification, remove the builds from the notification, then close VS, and clear the TFS cache (`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`). After that, re-run VS and Build Notification. The issue should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by delete the workspace and creating a new one again